# данные с cardview в другой activity

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

У меня есть recyclerview с cardview. я получаю данные для cardview через JSON. JSON отправляет данные с 6 ключей.В cardview я использую 3 ключа. Все работает нормально. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любой cardview у меня открывалось новое activity со всеми данными. Как это можно сделать?

У меня есть ViewHolder и OnClickListener. Я не могу понять как установить данные именно от карточки на которую нажали в activity которое будет открываться

Comment: И я все равно не понимаю смысл использования cardview тут.      
1. Делаешь класс модели с твоими тремя ключами, прописываешь в этом классе геттеры и сеттеры, делаешь разметку модели(то, как ты хочешь, чтобы моделька отображалась в ресайкле).      
2. Сеттаешь в каждую модель свои три ключа, кидаешь список моделей в адаптер ресайкла.
3. Вешаешь слушатель на ресайкл. У каждой позиции ресайкла своя модель со своими ключами.
4. Через интент геттерами передаешь все три ключа в другую активити и там делаешь с ними, что хочешь.

Comment: у меня есть фото, имя объекта и описание. для этого я использую cardview

Comment: Ну и? 1. CardView тут вообще не нужен. 2. Все три ключа имеют тип данных String. Вот и передавай эти String x3 в другую активити.

Comment: спасибо, я вроде разобрался с этим, удалил cardview и сделал все в recycler. Возможно ли с вами как-то связаться? Можете ли вы мне помочь?

Comment: Пиши на почту sharki232323@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.render(c,specialTechicals.get(position));

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class)
                intent.putExtra("MyObject",list.get(position));

    });
```

Вот пример holder:

```
public class MenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MenuHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);



    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
}
```

}

И вот сам интерфейс:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(int pos);
```

}